# Deployment of Azure Cosmos DB Sql API with Autoscale Throughput via ARM Template

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I was going through this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-sql-with-resource-manager#azure-cosmos-account-with-autoscale-throughput to create azure cosmos sql with autoscale throughput via arm template. I see the following error on deployment:

[image]

Can someone please let me know why is this error happening?

Here is my arm templates:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xyz92/ARMTemplates/master/stackoverflow.json
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xyz92/ARMTemplates/master/cosmosSqlDB.json
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xyz92/ARMTemplates/master/cosmosSqlDBAccount.json

Comment: I just tested these and they both deployed without error. If you modified the template the issue may be on your end. If you posted your ARM template it would be easier to tell. Thanks.

Comment: Please see links in the description. Thanks!

Comment: This is somewhat convoluted. Not sure why you are provisioning a Cosmos account in this way. I think the problem is because of the way you're passing the throughput. Just put this in your template with the Cosmos resource with throughput in the Options {} and pass in the throughput amount as an integer. This is simpler than trying to pass the entire json string.

Comment: btw, this will get more simple next week. We're changing our implementation and making this more correct. If you can, please wait a couple of weeks as we're going to rev our api-version and make breaking changes in our template schema.

Comment: Is passing throughout like below is not correct? 

"databaseThroughput": {
    "value": "[variables('throughputPolicy').Autoscale]"

Also, I’m already passing throughput in options:   "options": { "throughput": "[parameters('databaseThroughput')]" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There is a new api-version (2020-04-01) for autoscale which you should use. Do not use 2002-03-01 as it will be deprecated and will throw an exception if used.

You need to pass throughput in one of two ways. The parameter names can be anything you want. The samples I wrote have separate parameters because the minValues are different for each.

To provision a database or container with regular throughput it should look like this.

```
options: {
    "throughput": "[parameters('manualProvisionedThroughput')]"
}
```

Autoscale throughput looks like this.

```
options: {
    "autoscaleSettings": { "maxThroughput": "[parameters('autoscaleMaxThroughput')]" }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that now that it's GA the options changed from `ProvisionedThroughputSettings` to `autoscaleSettings` if you try to use the other one it will just generate a Collection with the manual throughput. The exporting templates are still exporting with `ProvisionedThroughputSettings`, so be careful

Comment: This is correct. I will update the answer since we've made a breaking change.